# Launch popup to select a certain type of product in the sale.order.line view

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-11

I have been trying since last couple of weeks to add a different BOM fields for each products in sales module order/quotations. But unfortunately I could not manage to do so. below is the screenshots and codes that I have done so far.

[image]

[image]

**Here is my codes:**

```
 from odoo import models, fields
 class bom_Listing(models.Model):
_inherit = 'product.product'

productName = fields.Char('Product Name')
width = fields.Char('Width')
length = fields.Char('Length')
color = fields.Char('Color')
```

**Xml View**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<data>
<record id="product_normal_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="model">product.product</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_normal_form_view"/>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
<field name="categ_id" position="after">
       <h4 style="color:DarkOrchid;">Add New BOM</h4>
           <field name="productName"/>
           <field name="width"/>
           <field name="length"/>
           <field name="color"/>
     </field>
     </field>
     </record> 
     </data>
     </odoo>
```

What I want is to select a specific product upon clicking the yellow highlighted button and straight away in the pop the fields under (Add New Bom) will be changed to different fields based on the selected product. If you guys could help me in solving this issue I would be very appreciated for you.

Comment: Shouldn't these length and width fields be implemented on model `sale.order.line` instead of `product.product`? Seems to me so, because you want to change length and width per order line (and product of course).

Answer (score 0):

You should change the productName field from char to many2one of **product.product** object.
Add an **onchange** method on **productName** field so that when you select any product from the list, onchange will fillup the other fields.